# How can I draw this table

Tags: tables

Is there any possibility to write "Effects on" directly above "Monitoring Pollution"

Code is:

```
\textbf{Effects on} \newline 
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Small increases in \end{flushleft}} & \textbf{Monitoring} & \textbf{Pollution} \\
\textbf{} & \textbf{($\mu)$} & \textbf{($w$)} \\
\begin{flushleft}Reward of inspector, $r$ \end{flushleft} & Ambigous & Lower \\
\begin{flushleft}Penalty on inspector for taking bribe, $p_t$ \end{flushleft} & Lower &  Ambigous \\
\begin{flushleft}Penalty on factory for givin bribe, $p_g$ \end{flushleft} & Lower & Ambigous \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Table in wrong structure]

Answer (score 8):

You can add it in the first row itself. Further, you need not use those `\begin{flushleft}` and friends as this is done with column specifiers themselves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcc}
                                             & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Effects on}}   \\
\textbf{Small increases in}                  & \textbf{Monitoring}  & \textbf{Pollution} \\
                                             & ($\bm{\mu}$)         & ($\bm{w}$)     \\
Reward of inspector, $r$                     & Ambigous             & Lower              \\
Penalty on inspector for taking bribe, $p_t$ & Lower                & Ambigous           \\
Penalty on factory for givin bribe, $p_g$    & Lower                & Ambigous           \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, you need to use `\bm` (from [`bm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm) package) at appropriate places to make the variables bold.

Comment: I've aligned the code of the table of clearify the maening of it; I hope it's okay.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Thank you. Really appreciated. :)

Comment: The documentation of `amsbsy` (which provides `\boldsymbol`) says “Note: It is recommended nowadays to use the `bm` package, which became available in 1997.”

Comment: @egreg OK, I changed. `amsmath` has become a habit for me. Hence the usage. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `MWE` based on `multicolumn`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Effect on}\\
    \bfseries Small increases in & \bfseries Monitoring & \bfseries Pollution \\
    & $(\bm{\mu})$ & $(\bm{w})$ \\
    Reward of inspector, $r$ & Ambiguous & Lower \\
    Penalty on inspector for taking bribe, $p_t$ & Lower &  Ambiguous \\
    Penalty on factory for giving bribe, $p_g$ & Lower & Ambiguous \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Several points:  I dispensed with the flushing environments, and used the `l` specifier of `tabular` to achieve it.  Also, I included your first line (`Effects on`)as a row in the `tabular`, but I used an `rlap` to avoid requiring some sort of multi-column approach.  I also set a group-limited `{\itshape ...}` before entering `tabular`, but moved the parens inside of math mode to keep them upright.  Finally, I removed the extraneous `\textbf{}` which served no purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\itshape
\begin{tabular}{l c c}
&\rlap{\textbf{~~Effects on}}& \\
\textbf{Small increases in } & \textbf{Monitoring} & \textbf{Pollution} \\
& $(\mu)$ & $(w)$ \\
Reward of inspector, $r$  & Ambigous & Lower \\
Penalty on inspector for taking bribe, $p_t$  & Lower &  Ambigous \\
Penalty on factory for givin bribe, $p_g$ & Lower & Ambigous \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `\begin{flushleft}` code is not appropriate here.  Instead, just use a `l`/left column specifier.

You can make the "Effects on" text center above the second and third columns by using `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Effects on}}` as shown below.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l c c}
   &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Effects on}} \\
\textbf{Small increases in\ldots} & \textbf{Monitoring} & \textbf{Pollution} \\
   & ($\mu)$ & \textbf{($w$)} \\
Reward of inspector, $r$  & Ambigous & Lower \\
Penalty on inspector for taking bribe, $p_t$  & Lower &  Ambigous \\
Penalty on factory for givin bribe, $p_g$  & Lower & Ambigous \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]